# Spring repository in Swing

Tags: java, spring, swing, javabeans, spring-bean

I have Swing application with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA and without beans.xml (I use just annotations). So started normally.
I used next annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.customerproject")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application { ... }
```

1.I have repository interface:

```
@Repository("profileRepository")
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {}
```

2.In main application class (**Application**) some method I declared with annotation @Bean - here I returned new instance of main frame (MainFrame) - work correctly, It's OK:

```
...// annotations
public class Application {
// ... method main, DataSource and other methods
    @Bean
    public MainFrame frame() { return new MainFrame(); }
}
```

So, started application - showing MainFrame window.

3.In MainFrame I call new frame (**CreateProfileFrame**) like:

```
CreateProfileFrame cpf = new CreateProfileFrame();
cpf.setVisible(true);
```

In 'CreateProfileFrame' I declared my repository:

```
@Autowired
private ProfileRepository profileRepository;
```

And have method for data manipulation - creating Profile from repository:

```
Profile pr = new Profile();
pr.setEmail(emailTextField.getText());
Profile saved = profileRepository.save(profile);
```

But have **NullPointerException** in last line from this code: profileRepository.save(profile); bacause **profileRepository** is null.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So question... - **how** can I use repository with **@Autowired** annotation anywhere in different classes or frames? Help, please.

Comment: For future references, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210144/autowiring-not-working-in-springboot-application/49781415#49781415).

Comment: it's application context related, future reference as well : https://itqna.net/questions/33008/spring-boot-autowired-jframe